# SQL server unable to create table in database because of permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server 2008 Express R2.
I was trying to test a couple of queries when i started getting this error:

```
  Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    The specified schema name "t_one" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

SQL:

```
  CREATE TABLE t_one.clients
(
t_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
colOne varchar(255) NOT NULL,
colTwo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
colThree varchar(255) NOT NULL,
colFour varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_testID PRIMARY KEY(t_id)

)
```

I granted permissions to my user profile just using the interface and after i clicked OK/save it didn't apply them - when I went back to the permissions for my user they were all unchecked again.

Comment: Does the schema "t_one" actually exist?

Comment: yes the t_one database is already created

Comment: are you using the SQL Server Management Studio? How do you actually login in the SQL Server? How do you execute the query?

Comment: Check if schema (not database) really exists: SELECT * FROM sys.schemas

Comment: Beware of syntax - if "t_one" is database name (and not a schema name) you should rather use query like CREATE TABLE t_one.dbo.clients (...) or CREATE TABLE [db].[schema].[table] more generally, or just CREATE TABLE [table] (...) or CREATE TABLE [schema].[table] being in context of proper DB.

Answer (score 19):

Try to run it this way:

```
CREATE SCHEMA t_one
CREATE TABLE t_one.clients
(
t_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
colOne varchar(255) NOT NULL,
colTwo varchar(255) NOT NULL,
colThree varchar(255) NOT NULL,
colFour varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_testID PRIMARY KEY(t_id)

)
```

Answer (score 1):

To check and create if the schema does not exist, you can have the following **running in a separate batch**

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    sys.schemas
                WHERE   name = N't_one' ) 
    EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [t_one] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]');
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To check whether the schema exists or not, try

`SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 't_one'`

2. If the schema `t_one` not exist, try running

`CREATE SCHEMA t_one`

3. If you don't have permission to create Schema,

`USE <database_name>;`
`GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO <user_name>;`
`GO`

Then create schema and run the code for creating the table.

4. In the case you have the schema and you are not having the permission to use it,

   `USE <database_name>;` 
      `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO <user_name>;`  `GO`

Then run the code to create table.

[Read Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql)